# MailGun sender domain

Tags: laravel, email, dns, mailgun, sender

First sorry for my English level...

I have a platform which send mail when a client sign in. 
I use mailgun. 
Send works with domains like hotmail, gmail or ***.net (which is based on gmail). 
But when I try to send to domain like ***.eu it doesn't work..
On mailgun configuration I disable **"certificate verification"** for outgoing mails.

I use the framework Laravel.

This is the error message that mailgun shows to me :

> Failed: postmaster@mg.***.***.eu → name@***.eu 'A new user
>   registered on the plateform.' Server response: 552 552 sorry, your
>   envelope sender domain must exist [mail115] (#5.7.1)

or :

> Will retry in 900 seconds: postmaster@mg.***.***.eu →
>   name@otherdomain.eu 'Welcome !' Server response: 450 450 4.1.8
>   : Sender
>   address rejected: Domain not found

Thanks for your response...